# Using NSErrorPointer make error on using a bridge between Obj-C and Swift

Tags: swift

I'm planning to use AZSocketIO on Cocoapods, to use socket.io. I want to use NSErrorPointer to get error in calling AZSocketIO#emit().

```
var emitError : NSError?
socket.emit("deviceInfo", args: deviceInfo, error: &emitError)
```

AZSocketIO.h:

```
- (BOOL)emit:(NSString *)name args:(id)args error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)error ackWithArgs:(void (^)(NSArray *data))callback;
```

If I run this program, I get runtime errors like this:

```
fatal error: attempt to bridge an implicitly unwrapped optional containing nil
```

How can I solve?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it seems like you forgot about the `callback` argument. Try `socket.emit("deviceInfo", args: deviceInfo, error: &emitError, ackWithArgs:nil)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try declaring `emitError` as `AutoreleasingUnsafePointer<NSError?>`. See also https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-XID_13

```
var emitError: AutoreleasingUnsafePointer<NSError?>
socket.emit("deviceInfo", args: deviceInfo, error: emitError, ackWithArgs: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot set nil to your optional variable.

```
var emitError: NSError? = nil
```